# Do Browsers generate self signed certificate for WebRTC sessions?

Tags: ssl, browser, webrtc, dtls

I have two Web browsers talking to one another over WebRTC. WebRTC uses DTLS for securing the communication. So do the browsers generate their own self-signed certificates and send it to their peer browsers during DTLS handshake?

Comment: hmmm... why do you need this? You must to have at least one server to place source files. Generating certificates at frontend is not typical as I know. Maybe you want to add end-to-end encryption? I'm not familiar with webrtc, but you can check https://webrtchacks.com/true-end-to-end-encryption-with-webrtc-insertable-streams/ or https://saltyrtc.org/

Comment: I'm not really sure how this differs from your previous question so I closed it as duplicate as this one since you've also accepted the answer there. Not that the accepted answer clearly says that the fingerprint of the certificate is send as attribute in the SDP. And apart from that this is the usual DTLS handshake with certificates, with the fingerprint of what to expect is pre-shared to each party using SDP.

Comment: the intent of this question was to know whether generating this self signed certificate is handled in the webrtc stack ? My question clearly mentions whether this is handled by browser ? My previous question was  a generic one for ( native application).

Comment: The answer is yes unless you specify a specific certificate in the config object passed to the RTCPeerConnection constructor.